C# EF core create dynamic dbSet and FirstorDefault
I need to find all FK keys. I have a code:
    public static List<string> GetAllRelations<T>(DbContext db, T entity) where T : class
    {
      var model = db.Model;
      var userEntity = model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
      var primaryKey = userEntity.FindPrimaryKey();

      var key = db.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.FirstOrDefault();
      var x = key.GetContainingKeys().ToList();
      var y = x.First().GetReferencingForeignKeys().ToList();

      var referencingForeignKeys = db.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys())
            .Where(fk => fk.PrincipalKey == primaryKey)
            .ToList();


      foreach (var foreignKey in referencingForeignKeys)
      {
        var entityFullName = foreignKey.DeclaringEntityType.Name;

        var indexName = foreignKey.Properties.First().Name;

        var entityType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseEntities)).GetType(entityFullName);
        var entityName = entityType.Name;
        if (entityType == null) continue;

        PropertyInfo prop = entityType.GetProperty(entityName);

        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(entityType);
        db.Add(instance);

        db.instance.FirstOrDefault();

last right line in the code is
var entityType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseEntities)).GetType(entityFullName);
but next one has a problem. The line
PropertyInfo prop = entityType.GetProperty(entityName); returs null and I don't know how to call
FirstOrDefault
Can someone help me?
Thanks
I need help,advice or simple example because I can't to make right solution

Forgot about this code right now, but explain what is needed. What GetAllRelations should return?

I know how to build any dynamic query, but I do not see reason of doing that. What you are trying to achieve?

Hi, my issue is simple: I need to find if a specific record in the main dataset has a relationship with any other dataset. However, not all collections are defined in the main dataset, which complicates the task.
